# Problem with $.json return status 0 in Cordova when run from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, backbone.js, phonegap

I have in my Cordova Phonegap project,  don't know why when i use

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:30124/token',
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  data: 'grant_type=password&username=user&password=123456'
});
```

but it always return  a status = 0, I have test that using postman and it's worked, I don't know why it doesn't work in my Cordova project.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: It's likely a cross origin request... or your device is not connected to internet etc. Please see the answers to  question marked as duplicate

Comment: Thank you, i solved the problem by using m middleware in my backend project